# Error: Expression 'undefined' used with directive is non-assignable

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/dJty6/36/

I have data from json like so

```
$scope.info={
 "company1":"this",
 "company2":"is",
  "company3":"sparta"
}
```

I am using `ng-repeat` to print all the data and I want to monotor for changes on the fields.

```
 <input type="text" ng-repeat="item in info" value="{{item}}" monitor-change>
```

I have a monitorChange directive like this:

```
.directive('monitorChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {changedFlag: '='},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var $el = angular.element(element);
      $el.on('keyup', function() {//bind to element
          scope.$apply( function() {
            scope.changedFlag =true;//on key press value is changed
          });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

When trying to change the data, I receive the error `Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'monitorChange' is non-assignable!`

I am printing the data in my view with:

```
{{changedFlag }}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You should post the actual error message you are receiving.  I'll update the question with the full error for you.

Comment: `scope: {changedFlag: '='},` but you're not declaring in the HTML any `changed-flag` attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. As you mentioned `scope: {caretPosition: '='}` in directive definition, we need to pass `caret-position="obj.changedFlag"` in the markup.
2. As `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each item, it is good to use the Dot notation for the changes to reflect in the controller's scope.

Here is the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dJty6/38/

Comment: also note, this could be a false positive; there is currently no way to change this value back to `false`; once the value changes to `true`, it will remain `true` even if all the changes the user made are undone.